Room in multiplatform issue: AppDatabaseConstructor has no corresponding expected declaration
Can't use room in KMP desktop project, after following this guide: https://funkymuse.dev/posts/kmp-room-setup/
It gives me this error when compiling: AppDatabaseConstructor.kt:5:22 'actual object AppDatabaseConstructor : RoomDatabaseConstructor<BusStopsDatabase>' has no corresponding expected declaration
The error is in an autogenerated file, I didn't created this:
public actual object AppDatabaseConstructor : RoomDatabaseConstructor<BusStopsDatabase> {
  actual override fun initialize(): BusStopsDatabase =
      com.mypackage.`data`.datasource.local.BusStopsDatabase_Impl()
}

this is my gradle file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeCompiler)

    // Room
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.room)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
}

kotlin {
    jvm("desktop")
    
    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)

            //koin
            implementation(project.dependencies.platform(libs.koin.bom))
            implementation(libs.koin.core)
            implementation(libs.koin.compose)
            implementation(libs.koin.compose.viewmodel.navigation)

            //retrofit
            implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0")
            implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.11.0")
            implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.18.2")
            implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.13.0")

            //room
            implementation(libs.androidx.sqlite.bundled)
            implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.swing)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    add("kspDesktop", libs.androidx.room.compiler)
}

room {
    schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "com.package.MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "com.package"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}

This is how I construct the database:
@Database(entities = [BusStopEntity::class], version = 1)
@ConstructedBy(AppDatabaseConstructor::class)
abstract class BusStopsDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun busStopDao(): BusStopsDao
}

// The Room compiler generates the `actual` implementations.
@Suppress("NO_ACTUAL_FOR_EXPECT")
expect object AppDatabaseConstructor : RoomDatabaseConstructor<BusStopsDatabase> {
    override fun initialize(): BusStopsDatabase
}


Which version of room/AGP are you using? I just tried this on my local side and I can see desktop code being generated through KSP.

Finally the issue was that I was creating the database in desktopMain instead of commonMain. I tried to migrate it the code from desktop to common but it was complex with Koin, giving me a lot of problems, so finally I did it from scratch based on how it done in this project: https://github.com/zsmb13/EkspenseTrakker
It haves Koin, Room and multiplatform, and it works... I hope they will make it easy to use Room in multiplatform in the future.
